# Get image directory from ImageView directory in javafx

Tags: java, image, javafx, imageview, geturl

ive been rectently working with javafx. In my code i've came across an annoying feature of javafx and i was wondering if there was a way of getting around it. Through my research ive realised 'imageview' nodes dont store the value of the image eg. location. I would like to get the directory from my imageview; which itself was passed through a class call. Everytime i use 'getUrl' it always returns as null which is annoying. when i set the image to the imageview it was set from a png image file so it should have a directory. There is the file name which i need for my code. This is a simple problem, for which i have no found a fix. Please help me

```
                           Image image = holding2.getImage();
                    
                           System.out.println(image.getUrl());
```

^^^^
this returns as null

Comment: Which `Image` constructor are you using? If you use `Image(String)` then `getUrl()` should not be returning null. However, it will return null if you use `Image(InputStream)`. Regardless, trying to get the source of the image from an `Image` object is, at least in my opinion, the wrong approach. Keep this information in the model associated with the `Image` / `ImageView`.

Comment: For such a question you should provide the code you use to create the image you set into your `holding2` variable (e.g. provide a [mcve]).  Also, an i is capitalized, always.

Comment: ill try another approch, the code setting the imageview's image its stretched over various files with userinput impacting the image so i could add the code. Thanks though, if you set your comment as a answer ill set it as a answer